# unit seconds since 2000-01-01 as datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

The time variable of my dataset has the unit 's since 2000-01-01', type numpy.float64. For example time[0] = 591667567.96861005
How can I converte this into a date string of this format: '2018-10-31T06:50:33'?

Answer (score 3):

Use a base date and `timedelta` with your seconds since `2000-01-01`.

```py
In [1]: from datetime import datetime, timedelta                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [2]: base_date = datetime(2000, 1, 1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [3]: d = base_date + timedelta(seconds=591667567.96861005)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 0, 6, 7, 968610)

In [5]: d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[5]: '2018-10-01 00:06:07'
```